# Sort by desc in adminator theme

Tags: sorting, datatables

I am using php/mysql and use adminator theme to show result table in datatables

https://colorlib.com/polygon/adminator/datatable.html

i used order by desc in sql query and when i print results it show correct results in desc form. but when i show them in datatable they are shown by asc. i tried changing below file by adding aaSorting : [[0, 'desc']]

```
/assets/scripts/datatable/index.js

import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'datatables';

export default (function () {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable({aaSorting : [[0, 'desc']]});
}())
```

but its not working.

Comment: Try with  "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]] instead of aaSorting.

Comment: i tried but it still always sort by ascending

export default (function () {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable({"order": [[ 0, "desc" ]] });
}())